# Cómo buscar un texto específico en un archivo externo e imprimir la linea completa en Python

Tags: python, string, find

Buen día, estoy tratando de realizar un script que muestre solo las líneas que contienen una cadena expefícifica, por ejemplo si se busca “@prodigy.net.mx" de un archivo externo en .txt. La salida que se espera es algo similar a lo suguiente, donde cada vez que se encuentra “@prodigy.net.mx" se imprime esa línea entera:

```
From stephen.marquard@prodigy.net.mx Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
X-Authentication-Warning: nakamura.uits.iupui.edu: apache set sender to
stephen.marquard@prodigy.net.mx using -f
From: stephen.marquard@prodigy.net.mx
Author: stephen.marquard@prodigy.net.mx
From david.horwitz@prodigy.net.mx Fri Jan 4 07:02:32 2008
X-Authentication-Warning: nakamura.uits.iupui.edu: apache set sender to
david.horwitz@prodigy.net.mx using -f
```

El código actual solo imprime el contenido del texto txt. cómo se podría imprimir toda la linea en donde esté ese texto específico?

```
def buscasig(regcorreos):
    iniciopos=regcorreos.find('@prodigy.net.mx')
    if iniciopos==-1:
        return None,0
    print(archcorreos.readline())
    return correo

def correos(regcorreos):
    listacorreos=[]
    while True:
        correo,finposic=buscasig(regcorreos)
        if correo:
            listacorreos.append(correo)
            regcorreos=regcorreos[finposic:]
        else:
            break
    return listacorreos

def main():
    with open ('registrocorreos.txt') as archcorreos:
        regcorreos=archcorreos.read()
    print(regcorreos)

main()
```

Archivo txt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CcFOtkwIdG534RvXdbr6ySAjEF3eQk4D/view?usp=share_link

Comment: `main()` nunca llama a `correos()` ... ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Sería, cómo puedo imprimir toda la linea en donde esté ese texto específico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El código original**

Lo más importante es que te falta llamar a `correos()`, así:

```
def main():
    with open ('registrocorreos.txt') as archcorreos:
        regcorreos=archcorreos.read()
        correos(regcorreos)
    print(regcorreos)
```

La función `buscasig()` tiene dos errores:

```
print(archcorreos.readline())
return correo
```

`archcorreos` es local a `main` y `correo` no existe.

El problema de fondo es que al leer todo el archivo de una, ya no sabes donde comienza y termina cada línea. Podrías ubicar esos indices, pero sería trabajo inútil.

Lo correcto es cambiar de enfoque.

**Solución Pythonesca**

Python es un lenguaje avanzado que permite codificar de forma muy compacta y simple.

Tenemos esta función que abre un archivo de texto, lo lee línea por línea e imprime aquellas que contengan el texto indicado:

```
def main():
    with open ('registrocorreos.txt') as archcorreos:
        for linea in archcorreos:
            if '@prodigy.net.mx' in linea:
                print(linea)
main()
```

Eso es todo lo que se necesita.

En Python un archivo de texto lo puedes usar como un *iterador* en un `for` o comprensión de listas. En este caso, la variable `linea` contiene una línea del archivo.

Como revisamos la línea de inmediato, no es necesario guardarla para después (igual está en el archivo).

Al procesar por línea me evito la complejidad de registrar donde voy en la búsqueda sobre el contenido completo.

Ah, y me evito leer el archivo completo a memoria de una sola vez, lo que hace muy mal para el rendimiento.